# Programatically select a marker with jQuery Store Locator Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to programatically select a marker on a map with the [jQuery Store Locator Plugin](https://github.com/bjorn2404/jQuery-Store-Locator-Plugin).

I have a jQuery click event that should trigger a marker selection.

```
// Init
$('#bh-sl-map-container').storeLocator({ //settings })

$('.select-head-office').click(function() {
  // Here I'd like to select a specific marker, 
  // Ideally, select a marker from a unique category. Ex: Head office
});
```

The plugin has the method changeSelectedMarker(), not sure if I could use it to solve my problem.

Comment: What do you mean 'select a marker'?  You mean trigger a click on it, change its icon, or just get the google.maps.Marker object so you can then access a property or method on that one marker?

Comment: By 'select', I mean bring it to the center of the map and trigger the info window. Basically, the exact thing that happens when you click a location in the locations list on the right side in this demo https://bjornblog.com/storelocator/v2/

Comment: What demo?  Give us a link please, I don't see an obvious one on that Github page.  Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow!  Please provide as much information to your questions as possible to help us with them.

Comment: Thanks! About the demo, don't you see the link in my comment? https://bjornblog.com/storelocator/v2/ Here it is again.

Comment: Can you have an array of your markers, which something on the object you're clicking (a data attribute perhaps) that will provide the connection with the relevant marker.

Comment: Thanks for your help @duncan, I eventually figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured a solution. It's a little hackish but it works well.

First, I realized I could use the list of locations to get the markers IDs, and associate them with the location category.

```
<li data-markerid="{{markerid}}" data-marker-category="{{category}}">
```

Then, with jQuery, I select get the markerId for the location with the category 'head-office'. (Ideally, a unique category)

```
$('*[data-marker-category='head-office']').data('markerid');
```

I created a custom method to pan to the selected marker.

```
selectMarker: function(markerId) {
 var _this = this;
 var map = _this.map;
 var infowindow = _this.infowindow;
 var storeStart = _this.storeStart;
 var page = _this.page;
 var selectedMarker = markers[markerId];

 map.panTo(selectedMarker.getPosition());
 if (_this.settings.bounceMarker === true) {
  selectedMarker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  setTimeout(function () {
    selectedMarker.setAnimation(null);
  }, 1200);
 }
}
```

Finally, I call my method with the markerid variable I got earlier.

```
storeLocator = $map_container.data('plugin_storeLocator');
storeLocator.selectMarker(activeMarkerID);
```